# Appartment elevator with login info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, saas, apartment-gem

I’m doing a Rails SaaS backend using Apartment gem and I need to use the data passed in the login as elevator. How do I proceed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [Custom Elevators](https://github.com/influitive/apartment#custom-elevator) for that

Comment: Yes I know, the thing is I don’t know how to get login data to do it. Apartment doc is quite vague on that. Any example?